# Sent transaction with incorrect memo. Now won't deliver

Tags: assets

I sent a XLM transaction from blockchain to bitmart but input an incorrect memo when sending. This has caused the transaction to sit in limbo. How can I correct this error so that I can receive my xlm?

Comment: This is a good discussion of the situation: https://medium.com/stellar-community/help-i-forgot-my-stellar-memo-d62b3cc9c2f7

Answer (score 3):

You can't correct a transaction once it's sucessfully submitted to the network. If the transaction went through and the recipient address was correct then bitmart has the money but can't assign it to you due to incorrect memo. You'll have to contact their support.